# How to remove JQuery dialog content after click on OK button or X(Close)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I have created JQuery function that creates dialog box. There is few arguments that can be passed in the function like HTML content, title, width, height. I started looking more in what is happening behind the screen when I click on OK button or X button. I see that Dialog box is set to `display:none`. All content remains on the screen. After I click on the next function that should make a call to dialog box I see that new HTML content is created. I'm wondering how I can clear the contest of the dialog box once closed? Here is my function for dialog box:

```
$.extend({ 
    alert: function (message, title, height, width, print) {
        var dialogButtons = {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        };

        if (print) dialogButtons.Print = function() {
            $(this).dialog().printArea();
        };

        $("<div></div>").dialog( {
            buttons: dialogButtons,
            close: function (event, ui) { $(this).hide(); },
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            width: height,
            height: width,
            overflow:"auto",
            position: {
                    my: "center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: window
            }
        }).html(message);
    }
});
```

Here is example how I call this function:

```
<div id="container">
   Some HTML 
</div>

//Call that creates dialog box
var divID = $('#container').show();
$.alert(divID,'Form Input',800,600);
```

Behind the screen I see this content after I close the dialog box:

```
<div style="height: auto; width: 600px; top: 0px; left: 655.8px; z-index: 101; display: none;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" aria-describedby="ui-id-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle"><span id="ui-id-2" class="ui-dialog-title">Form Input</span><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" title="Close"><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Close</button></div><div id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 468px; display: none;"></div><div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget">Ok</button></div></div></div>
```

And here is the content after I click again on the button that will open dialog box:

```
<div style="height: auto; width: 600px; top: 0px; left: 655.8px; z-index: 101;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" aria-describedby="ui-id-9" aria-labelledby="ui-id-10"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle"><span id="ui-id-10" class="ui-dialog-title">Form Input</span><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" title="Close"><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Close</button></div><div id="ui-id-9" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 468px;"><div id="container" style="display: block;">
</div></div><div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget">Ok</button></div></div></div>
```

Is this normal way for dialog box to create new html and set previous to display:none or I have some bug in my function?

Comment: Your title say remove the dialog box and your question says clear the dialog's contents. Which one is it?

Comment: Is `$(this).dialog("close")` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Barmar I tried to use .dialog("close"); but still content remains on the page.

Comment: It works for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bv3fgxbr/1/

Comment: @Barmar Open your dev tools and try to open dialog box. You will see html creates dialog box. After you click OK that will be set to diplay:none. Then if you click again on the dialog box new html code will be created instead of using previous code for dialog box. My question is if previous code can be used instead of creating new html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to solve this is to add a DIV to your HTML, and use that instead of constructing a new DIV dynamically. Its CSS should be `display: none;` so it's not visible until you show the dialog.

If you can't do that, you can save the DIV in a variable, and reuse it.

Then use `$(this).dialog("close")` to hide it while you're not using it.

```
var dialogDiv;
$.extend({ 
    alert: function (message, title, height, width, print) {
        var dialogButtons = {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        };

        if (print) dialogButtons.Print = function() {
            $(this).dialog().printArea();
        };

        if (!dialogDiv) {
            dialogDiv = $("<div>"); 
        }   
        dialogDiv.dialog( {
            buttons: dialogButtons,
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            width: height,
            height: width,
            overflow:"auto",
            position: {
                    my: "center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: window
            }
        }).html(message);
    }
});
```

There's no need for your `close:` option, since closing the dialog is the default action.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bv3fgxbr/3/)

Comment: I have tested your answer and works fine. I'm not seeing multiple elements created for my dialog box. Please can you explain why my original code was creating new div every time? I see that you check if div exist if not new element will be created. Is that the piece that I was missing? Thank you!